# Calling value in n-level nested list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am having an issue with calling 'hello'.
In first example, no problem:

`d = {'k1':{'k2':'hello'}}`

Grab 'hello'

`d['k1']['k2']`

Output: `'hello'`

But the second example, I cannot get my head around nested dictionary in list.

`d = {'k1':[{'nest_key':['this is deep',['hello']]}]}`

#Grab hello

`d['k1'][0]`

Output:

`{'nest_key': ['this is deep', ['hello']]}`

I tried `d['k1']['nest_key']` but it gets me error. I tried to look it up in docs but it didn't help.

Comment: `d['k1'][0]['nest_key'][1][0]`.

Comment: Okay, so `d['k1'][0]` gave you `{'nest_key': ['this is deep', ['hello']]}`, and you want to get the `['nest_key']` *of that*, so... you put `d['k1'][0]` and then `['nest_key']`, giving... (left as an exercise for the reader) and then you get `['this is deep', ['hello']]`, and then you want to do.... See how it works? I don't understand why you are confused. All you need to do is *keep doing the thing you already know works*.

Comment: I see! thank you for explanation. I was missing the [0] after first key. And as you said: _"keep doing the thing you know already works"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d[k1]` is a list with 1 element which is a dict.
so `d[k1][0]` accesses the 2nd dict.
`d[k1][0][nest_key]` accesses the inner lis which is `["this is deep'',[hallo]]`

so `d[k1][0][nest_key][1][0]` gives you the "hallo"

It is all about the square brackets defining lists within the dict